# Laravel: Create morphs() relationship nullable

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I want to create a one-to-one polymorphic relation allow null relation.

Example:

```php
  Schema::create('ps_assistances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('assistance_number', 50)->nullable();
            $table->morphs('assitanceable')->nullable();
  });
```

But this example return null when assing "->nullable()" to morph column.

I try to create _type and _id  manually and it works fine.

Example with manually morph column:

```php
  Schema::create('ps_assistances', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('assistance_number', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('assitanceable_type')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('assitanceable_id')->nullable();
  });
```

**I want to know if exists a better way to do a one-to-one polymorphic relation nullable.**

Comment: You need to change the accepted answer, because laravel now has nullable morphs

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`nullableMorphs` should handle this for you

e.g:

```
Schema::create('ps_assistances', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('assistance_number', 50)->nullable();
    $table->nullableMorphs('assitanceable');
});
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `nullableMorphs`

```
$table->nullableMorphs('assitanceable');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-nullableMorphs